# how to access array inside json object in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3

Can't access json object which is array inside json object
i want to access data from json object which have array inside array
and that json file is also uploaded 
so pls can anyone check and help me how to get "weather.description"
 data

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=13ae70c6aefa867c44962edc13f94404")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("some error occured")
        } else {

            if let urlContent =  data {

                do{
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)

                    let newValue = jsonResult as! NSDictionary

                    print(jsonResult)

                    let name = newValue["name"]
                    //Here i am getting name as variable value

                    //this is not working
                    let description = newValue["weather"]??[0]["description"]

                    //this is not working
                    let description = newValue["weather"]!![0]["description"]

                    print()

                }catch {
                    print("JSON Preocessing failed")
                }

            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

[image: can anyone help me to get that data from weather.description]

Comment: what Swift version are you using? 3.0?

Comment: Let's do it piece by piece. `let weatherValue = newValue["weather"]` returns? If it returns correctly, `let firstWeather = weatherValue[0]` returns? If it returns correctly, `let weatherDescription = firstWeather["description"]` returns?

Comment: its not working
its giving error 
"Type 'Any?' has no subscript members" 

is it possible because i am converting  result into NSDictionary

Because i tried most of the options and its not working and giving this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your code a bit, and added a few comments. Basiclly, lets check for the types of your response structure, and get the desired value.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=13ae70c6aefa867c44962edc13f94404")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("some error occured")
            } else {

                if let urlContent =  data {

                    do{
                        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)

                        // I would not recommend to use NSDictionary, try using Swift types instead
                        guard let newValue = jsonResult as? [String: Any] else {
                            print("invalid format")
                            return
                        }

                        // Check for the weather parameter as an array of dictionaries and than excess the first array's description
                        if let weather = newValue["weather"] as? [[String: Any]], let description = weather.first?["description"] as? String {
                            print(description)
                        } 

                    }catch {
                        print("JSON Preocessing failed")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

Comment: it worked and one more thing can u tell me why did u use this syntax

[[String: Any]]

and why shouldn't i use NSDictionary

Comment: `Dictionary` ([String: Any]) is a native Swift struct. `NSDictionary` is a Cocoa class. Try using native Swift language elements, if you are using Swift! Btw, if it works, mark it as accepted answer pls.

Comment: can i have ur email address or Twitter details

Comment: `let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)                        
                        if let items = jsonResult["items"] as! NSArray {
                            for item in items {
                                print(item["published"])
                                print(item["title"])
                                print(item["content"])
                            }
                        }`
if i am using this syntax its giving this error
type Any has no subscript member left